# Kernel Module Programming

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read and write to a proc file through kernel module
But when I run this command :

`echo "hello" >> /proc/hello && cat /proc/hello`

It doesn't print anything and when i open the file through text editor.
I found mysterious symbols like this

```
 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Any help will be appreciated 
thanks in advance

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

int len,temp;
char *msg;

int read_proc(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp ){
    if(count>temp){count=temp;}
    temp=temp-count;
    copy_to_user(buf,msg, count);
    if(count==0)temp=len;
    return count;
}

int write_proc(struct file *filp,const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp){
    copy_from_user(msg,buf,count);
    len=count;
    temp=len;
    return count;
}

struct file_operations proc_fops = {
    read: read_proc,
    write: write_proc
};

void create_new_proc_entry(void){
    proc_create("hello",0,NULL,&proc_fops);
    msg=kmalloc(GFP_KERNEL,10*sizeof(char));
}

int proc_init (void){
    create_new_proc_entry();
    return 0;
}

void proc_cleanup(void){
    remove_proc_entry("hello",NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

Comment: Just a remark: you copy something from user in `msg`, but `msg` has a size of 10 characters => in `write_proc` be sure to not allowed `count` more than 10, otherwise you will have a buffer overflow!

Comment: yup , you are right i appreciate this

Answer (score 4):

Apart from other problems of your kernel module (like boundaries check)

This

```
msg=kmalloc(GFP_KERNEL,10*sizeof(char));
```

have to be

```
 msg=kmalloc(10*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
```

With your call to `kmalloc` you are trying, probably, to allocate too many or not enough bytes and it refuses your `kmalloc` request.

You should always check the `kmalloc` return value to be consistent: `!= NULL`

Comment: ya you are completely right , thanks a lot , and i'm sorry for this bad implementation , i'm just a beginner in kernel programming and trying to understand how things work

Answer (score 0):

You can find kmalloc in slab.h:

```
static __always_inline void *kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    if (__builtin_constant_p(size)) {
        if (size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
            return kmalloc_large(size, flags);
    #ifndef CONFIG_SLOB
        if (!(flags & GFP_DMA)) {
            int index = kmalloc_index(size);

            if (!index)
                return ZERO_SIZE_PTR;

            return kmem_cache_alloc_trace(kmalloc_caches[index],
                    flags, size);
        }
    #endif
    }
    return __kmalloc(size, flags);
}
```